# Нужны ли запятые на месте скобок?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, обстоятельство

> Он() в течение часа() справился с заданием.

Кажется, запятая не требуется, но у Лопатина сказано, что «обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым». Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего обстоятельства обособляются с предлогами ***благодаря, вопреки, ввиду, в целях, в связи с, во избежание, вследствие, по случаю, по причине, при наличии, согласно с, в отличие от, в противоположность, наподобие, при условии, в силу, за отсутствием, несмотря на, невзирая на, спустя, независимо от*** и другими.

С предлогом ***в течение*** обстоятельства обособляются редко, хотя это возможно при условии выделения смысла данной части высказывания.

***Он в течение часа справился с заданием.*** - Подчёркиваем факт выполнения задания.

Хотите подчеркнуть, что он справился с заданием **именно в течение часа**? Тогда можно обособить: ***Он, в течение часа, справился с заданием.***

В Нацкорпусе 211 документов-предложений с сочетанием "он в течение ...", и нигде обстоятельство с предлогом "в течение" не обособляется, хотя это обстоятельство действительно находится между подлежащим и сказуемым.